# Test if window.open called from a callback was executed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function similar this one:

```
openUrl(): void {
  const url: string = "http://www.xpto.com";
  this.MyService.load(url).then( response => {
    const file = new Blob([response]);
    if (file.size > 0) {
      window.open(url,"_blank");
    }
  });
}
```

How to create a test to verify if the window.open was called with the URL?

I started to create the code below but I don't know how to mock the callback.

```
describe("Button for download", () => {
    it("should open the correct URL", () => {
      // given
      

      // when
      underTest.openUrl();

      // then
      expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith("http://www.xpto.com");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way

```
describe("Button for download", () => {
        it("should open the correct URL", () => {
          // given
          spyOn(window, "open");
          spyOn(MyService, "load").and.returnValue($q.resolve(["content"]));

          // when
          underTest.openUrl();

          // then
          expect(MyService.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
          $rootScope.$apply();
          expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith("http://www.xpto.com", "_blank");
        });
    });
```